# Literary synonym for "not a small thing"

Tags: synonyms, idiom-requests

Is there a *literary* or at least formal idiom which would mean ***not a small thing***, but does not include the word *thing* or *matter*? I need it for this sentence:

> The love of a mother or father is __________ [*not a small thing*].

I want the sentence to mean that this is not something that anyone can have and that can be regarded as something insignificant, casual, something that you can acquire anytime you want. It is special, admirable, not easily accessible.

I would not qualify the parents' love as a *thing* or *matter*. It would be preferable for the idiom to contain negation, but I will accept an affirmative one, too.

[PowerThesaurus](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/no_small_feat/synonyms) is a good dictionary of synonyms because it includes phrases, but in this case the options are not very tempting:

> - no minor matter
> - no easy feat
> - no small task etc.

Comment: There are lots of synonyms for trifle etc if you want a negation, but it's not obvious what connotation you want: something rare and precious, or something more common but still crucial to everyone (like air, shelter, etc), or something denoting excellence or achievement? Tasks, feats, and matters are very different.

Comment: @StuartF The adjective is not the problem, it is the noun that strikes me as informal. I could finally go with _... is not something insignificant/negligible/etc._ but I wanted to avoid "thing" and "something" altogether if it is possible.

Comment: Do you want the expression to remain as litotes?

Comment: @Greybeard I would prefer that, but if there is no idiom available, I will accept anything closest to the meaning.

Comment: You can't use your own *is not insignificant*?

Comment: @YosefBaskin I might have to in the end. I just feel it's more plain than "not a small thing".

Answer (score 1):

There is no term to replace with sufficient accuracy the word "thing", a term which refers to an existent in a perfectly uncategorizing way, while  introducing no connotations. The fact that it has to be relied upon so often is probably what gives this impression of it being a word of the common run, but perhaps that doesn't have to be. There are, of course, "entity" and "existent", but those, while not "common place terms" are too technical for the present purpose. I am afraid that a satisfactory term will be determined only at the price of introducing a miminum of connotation. There is the bias of acknowledging that "thing" through what people consider it to be in its most basic terms, that is, a *conception*.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/conception?q=conception)) **conception** [countable, uncountable] an understanding or a belief of what something/somebody is or what something/somebody should be
> conception of something
> • Marx’s conception of social justice

> (SOED) **conception**  **4** That which is conceived in the mind; an idea, a notion, a concept.

- The love of a mother or father is not a trivial conception.

Comment: Good introduction. However, I don't think I can use "conception", it sounds too sophisticated. I am just surprised I cannot find a simple but formal expression.

Comment: *conception* also suffers from being the usual word for the result of a mother and father expressing their love physically ... I'd have stopped after the first seven letters of the word.

Answer (score 0):

Alhough usually applied to things one has a special fondness for, you could use the phrase **prized possession** for such abstractions as *mother's love*, *father's love*, etc.